# Phase shift in ce configuration

Tags: transistors

Please explain,How a 180 phase shift occurs in "ce" Amplifier. Change in input voltage leads to change in output voltage is some how I know,  but this happen in "cb" Configuration too. When Vbe increases Vce  decrease(PNP transistor)

Comment: A "change" can be pos. or negative...Open your mind....

Comment: @LvW exactly.. That change can be found in CB configuration also

Comment: Are you sure...? Can you explain?

Comment: @LvW generally during a input signal operation if Veb increase then corresponding ly Vcb increase.. Correct me if it is mistake

Comment: Try to read this answer here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/404902/bjt-why-do-we-need-rc-and-re/404958#404958 where you can see that any increase in the base current will increase the collector current also. And large collector current means that we have a large voltage drop across Rc resistor. And transistor Vce voltage decreasing Vce = Vcc - Ic*Rc. Hence we can say that we have a 180 phase shift between the input and the output.  Any increase in the input decrease Vce voltage at the output and vice versa

Comment: Yes - in some cases we are allowed to use a transistor MODEL, where we assume that the BJT is current-driven (Ib controls Ic). However, this is only a model description. Physically spoken, it is the VOLTAGE Vbe that controls Ic. See the famous well-known equation from W. Shockley Ic=f(Vbe). This describes the classical exponential function that applies to any pn-junction.

Comment: cos(180 degrees) = -1.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top end of the collector resistor does not move.
Thus the bottom end, the output, has to move when the current changes.

But the 2 resistors are used at **opposite** ends, thus the phase becomes reversed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8YQnM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>